# Secure a Wireless Bridge (possibly with VPN)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I use a public WiFi for my home internet. I have bridged the WiFi with a TP-Link router. My router connects all our devices (Phones, Computers, TV etc). I am quite worried about the security of my setup since I am able to 'see' other peoples devices on the network (in fact I can cast to other peoples TVs!!). 
I'd like to have my own private (WiFi) network which connects to the public WiFi. 
Bearing in mind there can be no physical connection with the public router, how do I configure my router to connect to the public WiFi without any of my devices (except the router of course) being visible on the network? Do I need DD-WRT? Any informative help is appreciated. Thanks.

Keith.

Comment: What's the tp-links model number?

Answer (score 0):

Using consumer equipment, like the TP-Link, you'll need two such devices. Set the first up as a Wireless Bridge: acts as a WiFi client connecting to the public WiFi and bridges it to the device's Ethernet ports.  Then install a second router connecting it's WAN interface to the LAN interface of the first.

You said that your current single device is serving your network and you mention wireless devices. You don't specifically state whether the wireless devices are connecting directly to the public wifi, or to your bridge. If the later, this would normally require two WiFi radios: one to act as client to public WiFi, and an other to act as Access-Point.  In the unlikely event you have such a device, you'll want to turn off the access-point mode, use it strictly as a WiFi client (wireless bridge), and setup the Access-point wifi on the second device, which because it is also acting as a router, will offer DHCP to your computers on a new (different network number than the pubic wifi) and perform NAT (network address translation) to it's WAN.
 In this way, you have installed a firewall (2nd device) between your devices and the public WiFi.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Actually all my devices are connected to my router. I have connected my router to the public wifi by enabling WDS Bridging. I believe this is safer than connecting my computers diretly to the public wifi.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Actually all my devices are connected to my router. I have in turn connected my router to the public WiFi by enabling WDS Bridging. Therefore my router currently serves simply as a range extender. I don't want this. I want to have my own private network with a firewall which is connected to the public WiFi. My router obtains IP from public WiFi DHCP. So what do I need to do to create the firewall. Do I enable DHCP on my router and assign it a static IP from the piblic WiFi?

Comment: Are you running dd-wrt? Is your router model compatible? I saw you mentioned it in your post. If you are it would be In the config under the wireless tab > basic settings > wireless mode drop down > and choose client mode (not client bridge)

Comment: Keith,  which TP-Link?  There are a fair number of devices designed with bridging/extending in mind, vs using dd-wrt on a generic wireless-router.  I ask because, for generic routers, it would be unusual to be able to use the routers wifi to act as a client to the public wifi and also act as an access-point to your wireless devices. This would normally require two wifi radios. Some dual band routers may be able to do split personality: bridging one radio, while hosting an AP on the other. For simplicity, I suggested two devices: one as client-bridge, and a second to be your FW and AP.